# background-color input CSS specificity issue

Tags: css, input, css-selectors

I am trying to apply an `input:read-only` style, but it is not overriding the defaults for `input`, at least in Chrome.

[image]

I have reviewed the [laws of CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) in terms of what gets precedence (and [used this](https://specificity.keegan.st/)) and it all points to the read-only definition taking precedence. Yet, in the image above, you can see that the browser isn't using those styles.

My code is

```css
body {
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 300;
}
input:read-only {
   background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(220, 220, 220), rgb(59, 59, 59)) !important;
   border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133)) !important;
}
input {
   padding: 5px;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';
   font-size: 14px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value='read only text' readonly>
<input type="text">
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the -internal-light-dark of the Chrome, try to use a simple way.

```css
input:read-only {
   background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
   border-color: rgb(118, 118, 118);
}
```

```html
<input readonly>
```

If it doesn't work properly, please try to put in HTML a class e.g.color for specificity issue.

```css
.color {
   background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
   border-color: rgb(118, 118, 118);
}
```

```html
<input readonly class="color">
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below mentioned code

```css
body {
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 300;
}
input:read-only {
   border-image:linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(118,118,118,1) 0%, rgba(113,113,113,0) 100%);;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(220, 220, 220) 0%, rgb(59, 59, 59) 100%);
}
input {
   padding: 5px;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';
   font-size: 14px;
   width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" readonly>
<input type="text">
```